# Unrecognized selector when accessing properties of URLSessionConfiguration subclass

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, foundation, unrecognized-selector, nsurlsessionconfiguration

I wanted to subclass URLSessionConfiguration to set some default values for properties such as timeout intervals and httpHeaders. So I came with this custom subclass.

```swift
class CustomSessionConfiguration: URLSessionConfiguration {
    init(time: TimeInterval) {
        super.init()
        timeoutIntervalForResource = time
    }    
}
```

But when I instantiated `CustomSessionConfiguration` a crash occurred with the following reason:

`-[CustomSessionConfiguration setTimeoutIntervalForResource:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000021b76c0`

It seems that my subclass didn't inherit the setter method for `timeoutIntervalForResource`. Note that the same happens for other properties of the class such as `httpAdditionalHeaders`.

Answer (score 3):

After more carefully inspecting the documentation for `URLSessionConfiguration` I noticed that `init()` is marked as deprecated. This is a clear signal that the class is not intended to be subclassed as I was doing. In particular the call to `super.init()` in my subclass' init was probably creating a "broken" instance.

Moreover, if I create an instance using the `default` class method:

```swift
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
print(type(of: config))
```

I get the value `__NSCFURLSessionConfiguration` which indicates pretty clearly that `NSURLSessionConfiguration` is likely implemented as a [Class Cluster](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html) and this is probably the reason why `CustomSessionConfiguration` wasn't inheriting property accessors.